# SKIP (not execute the line) a line in perl debugger

Tags: perl, debugging

Is there a command or a way around skipping a line of code in perl debugger?
I have some random lines and functions in my executable file, so I though I should skip those function calls. Is there a command for it?
EDIT:I don't want to execute the subroutine calls!

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid there is no way to skip a line with the Perl built-in debugger.

For reference, see the discussion that the Perl Monks had regarding this issue: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=750710

Some suggestions include:

- Commenting out the line you want to skip. If during the debugging session you want to execute the commented out line, you can issue it in the debugger prompt.
- Add a variable for testing purposes. You can change its value from the debugger prompt.

```perl
    my $dbgln = 0;  # <- add this line
    if($dbgln){ original code of line to skip }
```

- Put a label after the line that you want to skip and issue a `goto` command from the debugger prompt.

Comment: That's unfortunate, is line-skipping it possible with other debuggers (Perl or other languages)? It'd be very useful for skipping running certain subroutines.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>n</kbd> skips over subroutine calls, <kbd>c</kbd> LINENUMBER skips over everything until the line is reached.

You could have found this out yourself by reading the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/debtut) and online help <kbd>h</kbd>.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to run them. I want to SKIP them